# shell script to rename a file name based on another file name

Tags: cmd, rename

I have 2 files in my folder. One is "TEST ONE.txt", the other is "LEARN NEW.vcd".
I need to create a batch script to rename the *.txt using the *.vcd. 
So the Batch script should rename the "TEST ONE.txt file" to "LEARN NEW.txt".

I have only one file with txt and one file with vcd extension in my folder C:\DEV folder.

I tried using the following script but it does not pick up the full name of the vcd extension and drops everything after the spaces - so I just get LEARN.txt :(

```
@echo ON 
CD "C:\DEV folder"
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /F %%A in ('dir /b *.vcd') do ( 
  set xname= %%~nA
  ren *.txt !xname!.txt
)
```

Thanks - db

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the default in `FOR /F` may be to only take one (1) token. You can force it to take all using `tokens=*`. Quoting is important.

```
@echo ON
CD "sub"
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%A in (`dir /b *.vcd`) do (
  set xname=%%~nA
  ren "*.txt" "!xname!.txt"
)
```

Comment: you don't even need delayed expansion and the variable: `ren "*.txt" "%%~nA.txt"`

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone stumbles across this the way I did, there is a more elegant solution that I was forced to devise because I wanted it to go through multiple sub-directories, rather than run it one directory at a time.  It is:
`forfiles /S /M *.vcd /C "cmd /c rename *.txt @fname.txt"`

Use your file extensions of choice.